# Fitting the Email content for mobile and desktop cilent

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, html-table

I would like to use 60% width and center the column for desktop client, however, for the mail client, use the 100% width

So far I have create two table to include the content like this:

```
<table class="table table-mail" style="width:100%; margin-top: 10px; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #afafaf; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #afafaf; -o-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #afafaf; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #afafaf; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#afafaf,Direction=134,Strength=5);">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="space" style="width: 20px; padding: 7px 0;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td align="center" style="padding: 7px 0;">
                <table class="table" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="60%" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
                    <tbody>
```

The first one is full width and the other table inside it is 60%, I would like to make it 100% for mobile but media query is not working in Gmail / outlook, how to achieve that result?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: or should I fix the width of the inner table, e.g. If I fix it as 650px , will it be too large for smaller screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Campaign Monitor's handy [CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) indicates that the vast majority of e-mail clients do not support responsive CSS. If you don't mind the lack of support for some versions of Outlook, you could use `max-width` instead but you would need to use a specific width instead of the 60% you want.

```
.table-mail{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:650px;
}
```

**UPDATE 29/04/16**

I've since discovered [MailChimp's e-mail blueprints on GitHub](https://github.com/mailchimp/email-blueprints) which include a few responsive templates. I haven't had opportunity to test them yet and they haven't been updated in 3 years but they may be of some use to you.

Comment: thanks, I would like to support outlook 2013 only, will check that

Comment: Unfortunately, from that guide, `max-width` isn't supported by Outlook 2013.

Comment: any workaround ? As I know the outlook is nightmare but need to deal with it